# How do I print the name and value of a custom data type in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, types, show

Lets say I define a data type as follows:

```
data OP = Plus | Minus | Num Int     deriving (Show, Eq)
```

Then I take a list of `strings`, and get a list of their respective `OP` values like this:

```
getOp :: [String] -> [OP]
getOp [] = []
getOp (x:rest)
        | x == "+" = Plus:(getOp rest)
        | isInfixOf "Num" x == True = Num (read (drop 4 x) :: Int):(getOp rest)
        | otherwise = "-" = Minus:(getOp rest)
```

I then want to show the `[OP]` list, separated by new lines. I've done it with list of Strings easily, but not sure what to do with a list of data types.

I have the following structure as a starting point:

```
showOp :: [OP] -> String
showOp [] = []
showOp (o:os) = (putStr o):'\n':(showOp os)
```

I know the last line is wrong. I'm trying to return a `[Char]` in the first section, then a `Char`, then a recursive call. I tried some other variations for the last line (see below) with no luck.

```
showOp o = show o  (works but not what I need. It shows the whole list, not each element on a new line

showOp o = putStrLn (show o)   (epic fail)

showOp o 
    | o == "+" = "Plus\n":(showOp os)
    | more of  the same. Trying to return a [Char] instead of a Char, plus other issues.
```

Also, i'm not sure how the output will need to be different for the `Num Int` type, since I'll need to show the type name and the value.

An example i/o for this would be something like:

in:

```
getOp ["7","+","4","-","10"]
```

out:

```
Num 7
Plus
Num 4
Minus
Num 10
```

Comment: Never ever say x==True. Just say x instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to look at the *types* of the functions and objects you are using. [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle) is a great resource for getting function signatures.

For starters, the signature of `putStr` is

```
putStr :: String -> IO ()
```

but your code has `putStr o`, where `o` is not a string, and the result should not be an `IO ()`. Do you really want `showOp` to *print* the `Op`, or just make a multi-line string for it?

If the former, you need the signature of `showOp` to reflect that:

```
showOp :: [Op] -> IO ()
```

Then you can use some `do`-notation to finish the function.

I'll write a solution for your given type signature. Since `showOp` should return a `String` and `putStr` returns an `IO ()`, we won't be using `putStr` anywhere. Note that `String` is simply a type synonym for `[Char]`, which is why we can treat `String`s as a list.

```
showOp :: [Op] -> String
showOp [] = [] -- the empty list is a String
showOp (o:os) = showo ++ ('\n' : showos)
   where showo = (show o) -- this is a String, i.e. [Char]
         showos = showOp os -- this is also a String
```

Both `showo` and `showos` are `String`s: both `show` and `showOp` return `String`s.
We can add a single character to a list of characters using the cons operation `:`. We can append two lists of strings using append operator `++`.

Now you might want another function

```
printOp :: [Op] -> IO ()
printOp xs = putStr $ showOp xs
```

Comment: That is very helpful, thank you. The only question I have is how could I incorporate printOp into showOp without changing the '[OP] -> String' signature so the result of showOp has each element on a new line of the output?

Comment: You cannot* incorporate `printOp` into `showOp` using the signature `[Op]->String`. As I explained above, there are two separate steps: converting the list to a `String`, and printing the `String`. Anytime you print, you need* an `IO ()` in the signature. *: Technically not true, but for your purposes, consider it to be.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
showOp = putStrLn . unlines . map show
```

Note that your data constructor `OP` is already an instance of `Show`. Hence, you can actually `map show` into your array which contains members of type `OP`. After that, things become very somple.

A quick couple of notes ...

You might have wanted:

```
getOp :: [String] -> [OP]
getOp [] = []
getOp (x:rest)
        | x == "+"                  = Plus:(getOp rest)
        | x == "-"                  = Minus:(getOp rest)
        | isInfixOf "Num" x == True = Num (read (drop 4 x) :: Int):(getOp rest)
        | otherwise                 = (getOp rest)
```

Instead of what you have. Your program has a syntax error ...

Next, the input that you wanted to provide was probably

```
["Num 7","+","Num 4","-","Num 10"]
```

?. I guess that was a typo.

Comment: Note, if you want to retain your type signature, just get rid of the `putStrLn` function ...